# PDF is blank when downloading from $http.get

Tags: angularjs, api, pdf

I'm retrieving a PDF from an AngularJS `$http.get` call, but when it downloads the PDF it's just a single blank page. What's weird is that if I open up the network tab and see what URL the application went to get that PDF, I can copy that URL and open it in another tab, and it downloads the PDF just fine. But when I go through the AngularJS `$http.get` it's coming out blank. Here's my setup:

**Controller**

```
function downloadPdf() {
    ReportsService
    .downloadPdf(var1, var2, var3)
    .then(function(response) {
        var ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/g);
        var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/.NET/g); // IE
        var oldIE = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g);

        var contentType = response.headers("Content-Type");
        var contentDisposition = response.headers("Content-Disposition");
        // parse to get filename
        var filename = (contentDisposition.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1]).replace(/"/g, '');
        // IE browsers
        if ((ie || oldIE || ieEDGE) && (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)) {
            var blob = new window.Blob([ response.data ],{type : contentType});
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
        }
        // Chrome  browser
        else {
            var file = new Blob([ response.data ],{type : contentType});
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            a.target = '_blank'; 
            a.download = filename   
            document.body.appendChild(a); 
            a.click();    
        }
    });
}
```

**Service**

```
function downloadPdf(var1, var2, var3) {
    var params = {
        "var1" : var1,
        "var2" : var2,
        "var3" : var3
    };
    return $http.get(url, {params : params}, {responseType:"arraybuffer"});
}
```

When I call the `downloadPdf()` function in the controller, it downloads the PDF just fine. But when I open it, it's a single blank empty white page. But again, if I open up the network tab to see what URL it just went to, the URL is exactly how it's supposed to be with the parameters in place and everything. Then I can open that same URL in another tab, and it downloads the PDF again, only this time it's not empty and contains the data that I need. So it seems like my controller class is messing up the download somehow, although this is the same logic I use to download CSV files in the same application and the logic is structured the same exact way, and that works just fine.

I have tried to hard code in the `contentType` with `application/pdf` and that didn't work either. And the empty PDF does have the correct file name, it's just the content inside is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping someone can come up with a cleaner solution, but here is my current dirty fix I just came up with. I'm just using `window.open` to open up the URL itself, and building that URL using `$httpParamSerializer`

**Service**

```
function downloadPdf(var1, var2, var3) {
    var params = {
        "var1" : var1,
        "var2" : var2,
        "var3" : var3
    };
    //return $http.get(url, {params : params}, {responseType:"arraybuffer"});
    window.open(url + "?" + $httpParamSerializer(params));
}
```

A dirty fix in my opinion, but it's working for now. I'll leave this question as unanswered as I really hope someone can come and correct my original code to make it work!